# What is the minimal value of the sum $a_1^{-2}+{\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty} 2(2^k-2)2^{-2k} a_k^{-2}$ given $a_1+a_2+...=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the minimal value of the sum $$a_1^{-2}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2(2^k-2)2^{-2k} a_k^{-2}$$ given $a_1+a_2+...=1$ and all $a_j$'s are positive?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you think this is a tricky problem in some way, with a counterintuitive answer?

Comment: I have found a sequence with the value less than 130. I guess that the answer does not have an explicit form, or has a very complicated explicit form. So the best way may be to merely calculate the answer. But I do not know how.

Comment: Have you tried the method of Lagrange multipliers? Write your expression as $S=\sum_{k\ge1} c_k/a_k^2$, differentiate $S+\lambda(\sum_{k\ge1}a_k-1)$with respect to the $a_k$, and so on...

Comment: Thank you. It seems that Lagrange multipliers yield a unique solution.